# Azure Logic App Create Blob gives Http 404 Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I'm having serious problems trying to create a blob file in an existing storage account/container.

To even narrow down the problem I forced the content of the blob to a fixed string (I have another sample where it works with a fixed string). I can't see what could be wrong with my connection since the access policy is "Container" (open doors for everyone and everything) and i'm pretty sure I'm using the right key (already tried both keys azure provides).

I even tested using a c# console application and the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer and both worked.

Simple schematic of my logic app

1. *When an HTTP request is received
2. *Decode AS2 message
3. *Check MDN Expected [if yes go to 4 else 6]
4. *Check MDN Type [if yes go to 5 else 6]
5. *Response
6. Response
7. *Create File [end logic app]
8. Response [end logic app]

NOTE: the steps with are the ones that get run, others are skipped

[image: Logic App Create File Blob]

[image: Azure Connection used for the blob container]

[image: Storage Account of the container]

[image: Container Access Policy]

[image: Error]

Comment: I can't tell from what you have above whether you are including the account access key (but you are right not to include it here). It looks like it's required in the dialog, so I'm guessing you did. The "container" public access setting is only for read access, however. In order to write to the container, you must either use the account access key, or use a shared access signature.

Comment: That's just a clarification. I'm not sure it will solve your problem. Can you add tags to this so that the Azure Logic Apps folks see this too?

Comment: I am able to repro this issue. Please correct the filename.

Comment: Hi @Tamra, are you sure the container option is only for read? With this option I'm able to send a file using a custom c# project (where I provide only the container name and the key). Also, in another example it works with this configurations.

Answer (score 3):

The blob names cannot have '<' chars please use the filename NOT having the special char (greater than, less than) in it.

You can use this

> @substring('blobname with <>',1,sub(length('blobname with <>'),2))

or just use guid function to get a unique file name and the content could be the AS2MessageId

> @guid()

function from [LogicApp WDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt643789.aspx) to achieve this.

Comment: Hi @TusharJ. Do you know how can I access the AS2MessageId inside the substring? I'm trying the following @substring(string(@{body('Decode_AS2_message')?['AS2Message']?['AS2MessageId']}),1 .... but it gives me an error saying the @ (before body) is invalid.

Comment: @FEST try using only 1 symbol "@" in your expression.

Comment: sorry the delay. It throws an error with only the first @